# Convert global map from sinusoidal to wgs84 using projectRaster and part of the data is missing

Tags: r, raster, projection

I am trying to convert a global map from sinusoidal to wgs84. I use projectRaster in raster package.
The original raster is here:

```
> ras_sinu
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 33600, 86400, 2903040000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 463.3127, 463.3127  (x, y)
extent      : -20015109, 20015109, -6671703, 8895604  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : C:\Users\jw2495\Desktop\Gap-filling\MODIS_fPAR\2015.01.09\sinu.tif 
names       : sinu 
values      : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

[plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNdz2.png)

And I use

```
llprj <-  "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
ras_wgs84=projectRaster(ras_sinu, crs=llprj)
```

get the results here:

```
 > ras_wgs84
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 33583, 85106, 2858114798  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.00423, 0.00417  (x, y)
extent      : -179.9998, 179.9986, -60.02026, 80.02085  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\jw2495\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEPstLE\raster\r_tmp_2017-12-13_123847_5260_78184.grd 
names       : sinu 
values      : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

[plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Es1C.png)

Part of the data seems missing. Anyone knows what happened?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reproducible example based on your info that suggests that it works:

Example data:

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
sincrs <- "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m"
llcrs <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"
data(wrld_simpl)
w <- spTransform(wrld_simpl, sincrs)
ras_sinu <- raster(nrow=336, ncol=864, ext=extent(-20015109, 20015109, -6671703, 8895604), crs=sincrs)
rs <- rasterize(w, ras_sinu)
plot(rs)
```

Transform:

```
rll <- projectRaster(rs, crs=llcrs)
plot(rll)
```

Perhaps you need to update `raster`. This is with

```
packageVersion("raster")
#[1] ‘2.6.7’
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Actually I tried to aggregate the original data from resolution of 500m to 5km first and then use the projectRaster. And things went well. I suspect it is a matter of the large number of pixels. Do you try with 33600*86400?

Comment: did you try that?

Comment: Hi! I tried with 33600*86400. It seems to work well. Although at last it shows:Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (2468074 of 16 bytes) when running projectRaster, the plot is complete.

Comment: So I really wonder the difference in this example and my original dataset and why strange results come out in my case.